# How to squash selected old commits to current local branch

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a branch checked out with local changes that looks something like this in Visual Studio:

```
------------- Incoming (from fetch):
   X      <-- HEAD of the remote "origin/dev"
  ...
   Z
   |
------------- Outgoing (to Push, not yet merge/rebased):
 A |      <-- HEAD of my local "dev"
...|
 C |
...|
 E |
  \|
   \
------------- Local History:
   |
  ...     <-- Common history of local/remote "dev"
```

What are the git bash commands to squash my local C through E commits together into one commit C' (don't want to mess with origin, and I want my HEAD to still be at A -> B -> C')?

Git squash commands that I tried operate on A, not on C thru E, after which I have to re-checkout from reflog. I wonder if I need to checkout C (causing A-B to float?), then squash C thru E. Then cherry-pick A-B back? I'm intermediate-level you could say if you can keep the commands simpler.

Comment: You almost certainly want `git rebase -i` here: `git checkout dev` and then `git rebase -i HEAD~5`, assuming you've counted commits correctly. There are many ways to do what you're asking but interactive rebase, and changing two `pick`s to `squash`es, is quite straightforward if your drawing is accurate.

Comment: This worked, thank you @torek. Nothing at first is intuitive with Git as it all seems to require some searching for what exactly you want (though you can always find it). I was able to simply do a `git rebase -i <commit id of the last commit from which I branched>` and then `fixup` on the 3 old commits I wanted to squash and combine them into one with a new commit message.